# is there a way to only cut the outside of this seam?

Tags: modeling

[image]

used union booleen now want to get rid of excess

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Please use the edit link and explain what you mean in clear terms.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure that i understand what you mean, but i'll give it a try.

1. Maybe you could use a boolean with difference instead of union?
2. Since one part looks quite flat you could try to select only those by Linked flat faces (ctrl+shift+alt+F) and a small angle setting...
3. It looks like the flat surface has a different material, so another option might be to select by material, as material assignments are not changed by boolean operations (as long as both materials exist on the new object).